# Solving a higher order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to learn how to solve higher order ODES, but not really getting it and getting really long answers which I don't think are correct.

So i have been given $x'''-x''-x'+x=tcost$ and after lots of working out and finding the solution to the complementary and particular parts i have got the answer as

$\displaystyle x(t)=x_c(t)+x_p(t)$
$=c_1/e^t+c_2e^t+c_3e^tt-\frac{\sin(t)}{2}-\frac{1}{4}t\sin(t)-\frac{\cos(t)}{4}+\frac{1}{4}t\cos(t)$

I assume this answer is too long and thus not correct? Any help much appreciated!

$\frac{3ab^2}{12ab}$

Thank you

Comment: For reference, you can get fractions by using \frac{a}{b} (this gives $\frac{a}{b}$). It might help tidy up your expression a bit, because I can't tell whether the last term is $\frac{1}{4t} \cos{t}$ or $\frac{1}{4} t \cos{t}$. Oh and \cos{t} gives $\cos{t}$.

Comment: i didnt need to know that just forgot hence edited before i even saw this! Any help with the question?

Comment: What is the $\frac{3ab^2}{12ab}$ about?

Answer (score 2):

You can verify your homogeneous solution by seeing that you have $3$ linearly independent functions which satisfy the homogeneous equation.  You can verify your particular solution by plugging it into the differential equation.  Having a long answer doesn't mean it's incorrect.

Comment: so is my answer correct or not?

Comment: Don't be lazy, check it yourself, I just told you how to.  If you have more questions about **how** to check it, then feel free to ask

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your answer is correct.

For the DEQ:

$$x'''- x''- x'+ x = t \cos t$$

$$\displaystyle x(t)= c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^t+c_3 t e^t-\frac{\sin t}{2}-\frac{1}{4}t \sin t -\frac{\cos t }{4}+\frac{1}{4}t \cos t$$

is a solution.

I reworked the problem and got the same result, plus did the checks to validate it.

Comment: Nice! $\quad \ddot\smile^{\ddot\smile}$